# Exposing EntityFramework 4 entities as IList instead of IObjectSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, iqueryable

I have a 'Customer' POCO entity within my Entity Framework 4 project. I want to expose my Customer entities to my upper layers as a generic list rather than an ObjectSet.

I have an IUnitOfWork interface which looks as follows:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
   string Save();
   IList<Customer> Customers { get; }
}
```

Down at my Entity Framework DAL (which implements the above interface) I have the following:

```
public class EntityContainer : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private IObjectSet<Customer> _customers;

    public IList<Customer> Customers 
    {
       get
       {
         if (_customers == null)
         {
             _customers = CreateObjectSet<Customer>("Customers");                    
         }
         return _customers.ToList<Customer>() ;
       }            
    }
}
```

However the 'CreateObjectSet("Customers")' line doesn't work. Every time I try to add a new 'Customer' nothing happens. Interestingly, if I revert to using an IObjectSet then the code works. For example:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    string Save();
    IObjectSet<Contact> Contacts { get; }
}


public class EntityContainer : ObjectContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private IObjectSet<Customer> _customers;

    public IObjectSet<Customer> Customers 
    {
       get
       {
         if (_customers == null)
         {
             _customers = CreateObjectSet<Customer>("Customers");                    
         }
         return _customers;
       }            
    }
}
```

IQueryable also works, but I cannot get IList to work and I have no idea why. Anyone any ideas?

## #

A correction to the original question. Using IQueryable doesn't work, nor does IEnumerable. This is because the Customer repository needs to provide 'Add' and 'Delete' methods to add/delete from the entity collection (add or remove customer entities in the above example). Neither IQueryable or IEnumerable allow you to add or remove objects; instead, an ICollection or IList must be used. This leaves me back at my original problem. I do not want to expose my collection to the repository as an ObjectSet. I want to use a type which is not tied to the EntityFramework i.e. - I want to use a generic list.

Has anyone any more suggestions? I suspect there's a straightforward way of doing this, but I'm not familiar enough with the framework to figure it out.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is even more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_customers.ToList() is the culprit.  ToList executes the query and copies all the items from that query into a new collection object.   this new collection object does not provide the tracking capabilities that ObjectSet has.

Comment: Ok, thats good info thanks. Based on your comments and the previous posting from Justin I should either stick with IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>, or else perform the conversion to an IList at some other point in my code after the changes to the ObjectSet have been changed, at which point I don't care about the tracking capabilities of ObjectSet anymore. Thanks again!

Comment: I would love to..however I still have an issue now I'm testing this. I was incorrect when I stated earlier that IQueryable works. My 'Find()' method works with IQueryable, but my 'Add' and 'Delete' methods within my customer repository won't work because you cannot add to an IEnumerable. For this you must use and ICollection or an IList, which leaves me back at my original problem. I need to expose my entities as a collection which I can add to and remove from, but I cannot use the ObjectSet type. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a Repository in all of this. The Repository is usually what handles the conversion from `ObjectSet<T>` to `IList<T>` (or, in most cases, `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`).

```
public class EntityContainer : ObjectContext
{
    private IObjectSet<Customer> _customers;

    public IObjectSet<Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return _customers ?? 
                ( _customers = CreateObjectSet<Customer>("Customers");
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerRepository
{
    EntityContext _context = new EntityContext();

    public IQueryable<Customer> FindAll()
    { 
        return _context.Customers;
    }

    public Customer FindById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == id);
    }

    // And so on.
}
```

I usually then have my UnitOfWork create the Repositories that should be enlisted in the Unit of Work so that anything done through the repositories is bundled in a single operation.

Keep in mind, that my UnitOfWork only would have two methods. One for getting a repository and another for committing the Unit of Work. All data retrieval is handled by the Repositories.

Comment: Hi, I'm not missing the Repository or Unit of Work but I didn't mention them here because they're quite simple and I know they are working as expected. My pattern is pretty much exactly what you've described above actually. You say you usually use the repository to convert from ObjectSet to IList. I might try this approach, instead of doing the conversion down at my Entity Framework level thanks.