# How to Database to IList?

Tags: database, entity-framework, ilist

I have an application. Data for the application comes from a stored procedure. I am using Entity Framework to connect to the database. I want to get the results of that stored procedure to an IList. How can I do this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the another question - [Entity framework 3.5, mapping stored procedure results to custom entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902851/entity-framework-3-5-mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-custom-entity).

[Following link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/03/13/mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-a-custom-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx) will help with function import.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597268/exposing-entityframework-4-entities-as-ilist-instead-of-iobjectset) will help with IList result

Also [ADO.NET Entity Framework Extensions](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) can be useful